# Azure Media Player playback error (0x10600003)

Tags: regex, azure, azure-functions

So a while ago, we started utilizing Azure Media Player to play videos on out website and it has worked perfectly until recently.

The links that used to work:

> http://trueiqmediaservice.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/1002f113-9ccc-49a9-8549-c4bebabb47ee/Why are we makin.ism/manifest

Here is the method to define the regex:

```
private function register_embed_handler()
{
    wp_embed_register_handler(
        'f',
        '#((http[s]?):\/)?(\/)(\/)?fhtrueiqmediaservice\.streaming\.mediaservices\.windows\.net\/?(.*)_(.*).ism\/manifest#',
        [$this, 'wp_embed_register_handler']
    );
}
```

Well.. Looks like Azure updated how they handle links, so it was changed to this:

> https://mediasvcclqg331kwhpnq.blob.core.windows.net/asset-ab84ad2b-3ae4-4024-afd3-8f12cdecc266/2020-02-03 Crispin EDIT 2_1.mp4?sv=2017-04-17&sr=c&si=8b3d0ab4-5d65-470e-a26e-f7e65782f36a&sig=UW1aCdpqR7g2GSUeCD5ASiEazkSMl7q4SwiDLhtfHdQ%3D&st=2020-04-16T19%3A16%3A07Z&se=2120-04-******

How would I go about tackling that regex used in the new link? I'm terrible with regex and have no clue how to even start tackling this. All help would be appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your previous pattern was quite specific, and the new link is a bit longer.

You could for example use a pattern making the first part specific and if `.mp4` should always be present, make sure to match that.

As the only possible spaces in the example link are in the filename of `.mp4`, you could match the rest of the string using `\S*` matching 0+ occurrences of a non whitespace char.

```
https?:\/\/[^.\s]+\.blob\.core\.windows\.net\/asset-[a-f0-9]+(?:-[a-f0-9]+)+\/.*?\.mp4\S*
```

**Explanation**

- `https?:\/\/` Match the protocol with optional s, then `://`
- `[^.\s]+` Match 1+ times any char except a `.` or whitespace char *(The first part of the url might look like it is a bit randomized. If it is not, you can match it literally instead)*
- `\.blob\.core\.windows\.net\/asset-` Match `.blob.core.windows.net/asset-`
- `[a-f0-9]+(?:-[a-f0-9]+)+` Match a guid like pattern where the hyphened part is repeated 1 or more times
- `\/.*?\.mp4` Match `/` followed by as least a possible chars until `.mp4` is encountered
- `\S*` Match 0+ times a non whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OSXpFY/1)

Comment: Thanks for this clear description @The fourth bird, this made total sense and I got it working but never circled back on the answer! If the question made sense, could you please upvote it?